# STL vector and unique_ptr with custom deleter classes

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have some c++ code that compiles with clang 3.2-7 and gcc 4.8.1 but not with gcc 4.6.3.  I'm compiling with c++0x.

I'm implementing a 'ResourcePool' that manages a fixed set of resources.  It allocates resources out by providing a unique_ptr with a custom deleter class; when the object requesting the resource drops out of scope, the deleter returns the resource to a pool.

The deleter class looks like so:

```
template <typename T>
class ResourcePoolManager {
public:
    ResourcePoolManager(ResourcePool<T> & pool)
    : pool(pool)
    {
    }

    ~ResourcePoolManager() {};

    void operator()(T* releasedResource) const {
        pool.releaseResource(releasedResource);
    }
private:
    ResourcePool<T> & pool;
};
```

The pool itself looks like (edited unrelated methods out):

```
template <typename T>
class ResourcePool {
public:
    ResourcePool()
    : manager(*this)
    {
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T, ResourcePoolManager<T>> requestResource() {
        if(availableResources.size() == 0) {
            return std::unique_ptr<T, ResourcePoolManager<T>>(NULL, manager);
        } else {
            T * resource = availableResources.front();
            availableResources.pop_front();
            return std::unique_ptr<T, ResourcePoolManager<T>>(resource, manager);
        }
    }
private:
    friend class ResourcePoolManager<T>;

    void releaseResource(T * releasedResource) {
        availableResources.push_back(releasedResource);
    }

    ResourcePoolManager<T> manager;
    std::deque<T *> availableResources;
    std::deque<T *> allResources;
};
```

The problem occurs when I try to pull resources out of the pool and store them in a `std::vector;` where OpenCLDevice is the resource in question:

```
ResourcePool<OpenCLDevice> computeDevicePool;
std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>> devicePtr = computeDevicePool.requestResource();
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>>> gpus;
gpus.push_back(std::move(devicePtr));
```

As mentioned up top, clang and a newer version are gcc are fine with this. However gcc 4.6.3 is coming out with:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = OpenCLDevice, _Dp = ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >]':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:319:4:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> > >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> > > >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >*]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> > >]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:840:9:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> > >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<OpenCLDevice, ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> >]'
trunk/src/dpa/distinguishers/GenericOpenCLDPA.cpp:109:39:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unique_ptr.h:176:2: error: use of deleted function 'ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>& ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>::operator=(const ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>&)'

ResourcePool.hpp:30:7 error: 'ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice> & ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>::operator=(const ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>&)' 
is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
ResourcePool.hpp:30:7: error: non-static reference member 'ResourcePool<OpenCLDevice>& ResourcePoolManager<OpenCLDevice>::pool', can't use default assignment operator
```

The compiler stops at the final line where the pointer is moved into the `gpus` vector, indicating to me that something is being copied when it shouldn't be. Line 30 is the definition of the ResourcePoolManager class `class ResourcePoolManager {`.

Am I doing something incorrectly with the management of the custom deleter where the newer compilers are letting me get away with things?

Comment: can you mark line 30?

Comment: Sure---it's the definition "class ResourcePoolManager {"

Comment: Is there any more to the error message?

The compiler wants to copy the deleter object.  This is not possible because of member `ResourcePool<T> & pool;`.  I'm not sure if it's okay for the compiler to need to copy the deleter, but it seems work-aroundable.

I'm guessing it wants to copy in lines like this... `return std::unique_ptr<T, ResourcePoolManager<T>>(resource, manager);`

Comment: You might be able to work around this with `std::unique_ptr<T, ResourcePoolManager<T> &>(NULL, manager);` (i.e. using a reference for the deleter type)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the libstdc++ 4.6 `unique_ptr` that expects the deleter type to be copyable. [Changing `ResourcePoolManager::pool` to a pointer instead of a reference is an effective workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3fe3be3535143d6).

Comment: QuestionC - there is, thanks.  I've edited it in.

Comment: @Casey - you're the man, that is it thanks.  I don't see anywhere I can mark your comment as an answer, let me know if there's a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the libstdc++ 4.6 `unique_ptr` that expects the deleter type to be copyable. [Changing `ResourcePoolManager::pool` to a pointer instead of a reference is an effective workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3fe3be3535143d6).

More specifically, this program reproduces the bug:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct deleter {
    deleter() : c(*"") {}
    void operator () (int *) const {}
    deleter(deleter&&) = default;
    deleter& operator = (deleter&&) = default;
    const char& c;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int, deleter>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int, deleter>{});
}
```

simply declaring the vector is fine, its the instantiation of `push_back` that fails.

Clarification: the issue seems to be that the 4.6 implementation of `vector` is using `=` to move assign elements when it resizes, whereas the 4.8 implementation is exclusively using move construction. A class with a reference member  - such as your deleter - is move constructible, but not move (or copy, for that matter) assignable. [You can see the same error message in 4.8 if you assign to the vector](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/112c19739e9f712e):

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int, deleter>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int, deleter>{new int(42)});
    vec[0] = std::unique_ptr<int, deleter>{new int(42)};
}
```

[`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is specified to require only that `T` be `MoveInsertable`, so I believe this is certainly a bug in libstdc++ 4.6.